# RedGate SQL Prompt - Cursor Snippet mistake

Tags: t-sql, cursors

Using RedGate's SQL Prompt & loving it.  But I used the "curff" snippet for the first time today ("Fast-forward read-only cursor"), and it produced the following TSQL (which I've filled in to make it a concrete example):

```
DECLARE @variable INT
DECLARE Curse CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT ID FROM #TempTable

OPEN Curse
FETCH NEXT FROM Curse INTO @variable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM Curse INTO @variable  --This seems wrong...

    PRINT ('Hello, I am # ' + CAST(@variable AS VARCHAR(10)))
END

CLOSE Curse
DEALLOCATE Curse
```

Isn't the location of the inner `FETCH NEXT` (inside the `WHILE` loop) ***incorrect***?  It should be at the **end** of the loop, or at least *after* the query (queries) that need to use the variable, no?

Answer (score 1):

YES, it is **incorrect**.  The inner `FETCH NEXT` should go at the ***END*** of the loop.  The code above would result in the following:

```
Hello, I am # 2
Hello, I am # 3
Hello, I am # 4
Hello, I am # 5
Hello, I am # 5
```

Correcting the problem, and putting the `FETCH NEXT` at the end of the loop, results in the correct & expected output:

```
Hello, I am # 1
Hello, I am # 2
Hello, I am # 3
Hello, I am # 4
Hello, I am # 5
```

Now to go submit this to RedGate...

Comment: Sample code at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/32258/1

Comment: Apparently it's old-ish news -- https://forums.red-gate.com/viewtopic.php?f=169&t=78979&hilit=curff .. but I'm hopeful that they'll fix it and/or this post will help people catch the mistake.

Comment: And in less than 24 hours they've put out a fix!  Love how responsive they are.  :)